# Install jdk in centos

Tags: centos7

I tried to execute in CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core):

```
sudo yum install java-8-openjdk-devel
```

But I got error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
To enable Red Hat Subscription Management repositories:
subscription-manager repos --enable <repo>
To enable custom repositories:
yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

After I tried

```
 subscription-manager register --username test--password testing --auto-attach
```

But I got other error

```
subscription-manager: command not found
```